# On inspecting a html page I see different values being shown in "Computed" section and "Layout" section for a DIV element. Why is it so?

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom, microsoft-edge, web-inspector

On inspecting a html page I see different values being shown in "Computed" section and "Layout" section for a DIV element. Why is it so.

[Computed Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4oLS.png)

Q1 - In above: I am thinking, 100 is width and 0 is height. Is that right?

[Layout Section:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8anJ.png)

In layout section it show both height and width as 100px.

Q2 - how can the values differ in these two sections. And which wins.

Q3 - the height and width are in dull color, does it imply that these values are inherited from parent element.

Comment: sof does not show images in the body?? i think it showed images in the body earlier. If someone can edit and fix it.. it will be very nice. I tried but could not get the images displayed in the body of question.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's happening here without a live demo. It does look like the grayed-out versions are being overridden.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve]

Comment: Only one question at a time, please. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that the box-sizing attribute of this element is "border-box" from your pictures. And the 100px height in the layout means `content height + padding top + padding bottom = 100px`. And from the computed section we can see the padding bottom is 100px, so its content height will be computed into 0px.
We can infer that its CSS source code is like:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Wish my answer is understandable.